# Asterisk in stylesheet. VS gives me warning

Tags: html, css

I have following 2 lines in CSS file (I'm not CSS/html guy)

```
#main_text{background:#0083c3; padding-right:23px; *height:1%;}

#container{height:auto; *height:1%; padding-bottom:22px;}
```

Visual Studio 2010 gives following warning:

```
Unexpected character sequence. Expected a property name for the "<property> : <value>" declaration.
```

Do I need those asterisks and what do they mean?

Comment: You see the warning because this is IE only hack, not standard CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are there for IE7 and older to apply the styles. Other browsers (including IE8 and newer) will ignore those `height` styles, as they are invalid CSS.

If you're not interested in supporting IE7 and older, you should take them out so that your CSS will validate and Visual Studio will no longer complain.